# Get child routes in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, routes

How can I get all childes route of a specific route ?
for example get all childs of zfcadmin route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to grab the service-key `router` from the `ServiceManager`. This will give you the router for your application. The returnValue will be of type `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack`. From that point onwards you should be good to go.